# Why isn't my method being defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following errors. I am new to programming and I understand this as a problem with the digest method not being defined. However, in my User Method it is being defined as User.Digest(string). Hoping someone can send me in the right direction to help with getting this fixed.

**ERROR 1**

```
ERROR["test_current_user_returns_nil_when_remember_digest_is_wrong", SessionsHelperTest,   0.722231]
test_current_user_returns_nil_when_remember_digest_is_wrong#SessionsHelperTest (0.72s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for true:TrueClass
        app/models/user.rb:38:in `authenticated?'
        app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:21:in `current_user'
        test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:SessionsHelperTest>'
    app/models/user.rb:38:in `authenticated?'
    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:21:in `current_user'
    test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:SessionsHelperTest>'
```

**ERROR 2**

```
ERROR["test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil", SessionsHelperTest, 0.736168]
 test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil#SessionsHelperTest (0.74s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for true:TrueClass
        app/models/user.rb:38:in `authenticated?'
        app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:21:in `current_user'
        test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:SessionsHelperTest>'
    app/models/user.rb:38:in `authenticated?'
    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:21:in `current_user'
    test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:SessionsHelperTest>'
```

**SessionsHelperTest**

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

 def setup
  @user = users(:kyle)
  remember(@user)
 end

 test "current_user returns right user when session is nil" do
  assert_equal @user, current_user
  assert is_logged_in?
 end

 test "current_user returns nil when remember digest is wrong" do
  @user.update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(User.new_token))
  assert_nil current_user
 end
end
```

**User Method**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessor :remember_token
 before_save { email.downcase! }
 validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
 VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
 validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, 
                        format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
 has_secure_password
 validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

# Returns the hash digest of the given string. 
 def User.digest(string)
  cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                              BCrypt::Engine.cost
  BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
 end

#Returns a random token.
 def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
 end

#Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions 
 def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
 end

# Forgets a user. 
 def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
 end

    #Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
 def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember.digest).is_password?(remember_token)
 end
 end
```

**module SessionsHelper**

```
# Logs in the given user.
 def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
 end

#Remembers a user in a persistent session.
 def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
 end

#Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user
   if (user_id = session[:user_id])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
   elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
     log_in user
     @current_user = user
  end
end
end

#Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise. 
 def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil? 
 end

    # Forgets a persistent session.
 def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
 end

# Logs out the current user.
 def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
 end
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're invoking `remember.digest`. `remember` is a method which returns a *boolean* value , `true`, hence your error message:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `digest' for true:TrueClass

Given the code in context...

```
return false if remember_digest.nil?
BCrypt::Password.new(remember.digest).is_password?(remember_token)
```

...it's pretty obvious the second line should use `remember_digest`, not `remember.digest`:

```
BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
                             |
    underscore, not period --'
```

Comment: That did it, so remember_digest is the variable i've created whereas remember by itself is a boolean statement. Thanks Meagar!